# Update attribute for specific element using core data

Tags: swift, core-data

I am working with core data to store different activities and keep track of how many times each activity has been performed. The entity is called "Activities" with attributes "name" and "total". When an activity has been performed more than once, I want to change the attribute "total" (By adding +1) for that specific activity, instead of adding a new activity. How can I do this? This is my code so far:

```
    let appDel = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Activities")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"(name == %@)", name)

do {
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)  as! [Activities]

        if results.count == 0 {
            newActivity.setValue(1, forKey: "total")
            newActivity.setValue(name), forKey: "name")
            do {
                try context.save()

            }

            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

  }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update (if I am not mistaken), you can just change the `total` like this:

```
results.total = YourWantedNumber or results.setValue(YourWantedNumber, forKey: "total")
context.save()
```

Comment: This works fine, except that the element seems to "duplicate itself". For every time an activity is updated, an element with the following attributes is added:

   name = nil;
    total = 0;